# My App is crashing when trying to replace fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm working with the preset navigation bar in the android studio activity creation, when I try and replace two fragments the app crashes. I have tried to use both the

> import android.app.FragmentManager;

as well as the

> import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;

I was having trouble defining the fragment to be swapped out with the seconds import so I was not able to test it using that import.

MainActivity Java Script

```
package acook.mobileassignment;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                setTitle("Music Main");
                FragmentManager fragManager = getFragmentManager();
                MusicMain fragment = new MusicMain();
                FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = fragManager.beginTransaction();
                fragTransaction.replace(R.id.mainContent, fragment);
                fragTransaction.commit();

                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "MusicPageCheck!";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                setTitle("Timer Set");
                FragmentManager fragManager2 = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragTransaction2 = fragManager2.beginTransaction();
                fragTransaction2.replace(R.id.mainContent, new TimerSet()).commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                setTitle("Favourites");
                FragmentManager fragManager3 = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragTransaction3 = fragManager3.beginTransaction();
                fragTransaction3.replace(R.id.mainContent, new Favourites()).commit();
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
}

}
```

Comment: It would be great if you share the crash message or a stack trace

Comment: This won't be helpful in the slightest but it's working now for no reason, I didn't change anything at all in between it crashing and it working. I just left it for 2 hours and tried again. it works now

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using getSupportFragmentManager() with the 
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager, instead the getFragmentManager() ?

Comment: I have used that while trying android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager but I had the issue of whenever I create a fragment to place in the fragmentTransaction.replace it comes up with the error along the lines of 

"Wrong second argument type. Found: acook.mobileassignment.MusicMain, required android.support.v4.app.Fragment"

and I could not figure out how to turn it into a support.v4.app

Comment: I suppose this error appears because MusicMain extends Fragment but not the one from the support library. Check the import.

Comment: I changed the import to support.v4 in the fragment scripts and there is no longer an error so thank you very much for that @jeprubio. However the initial error still persists. Crashing on button press when trying to switch fragments, I am replacing the fragments to a frame layout, would it have something to do with the issue?

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the explicit stacktrace of the crash?